# CBP: Server, unattended-updates and vmware tools?

Tags: server, vmware, headless, unattended-upgrades

What's current best practice for headless VMware servers and automatic security updates? For non-critical servers I currently set auto-updates with a reboot, but because I've installed vmware-tools from the host I often need to manually re-run /usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl to get the modules updated. A pain.

- Does anyone here have thoughts on "Would you like to enable VMware automatic kernel modules?" when running /usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl?
- Should I move from the host-supplied vmware-tools to (a) those from the repos at http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx or (b) the multiverse open-vm-tools? - and do these actully resolve the modules problem?